# Shell Script to get exception from logs for last one hour

Tags: shell, parsing, grep, solaris, tail

I am developing script which will grep logs of last one hour and check any exception and send email for solaris platform.

I did following steps

```
grep -n -h date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' test.logs
```

above command gives me line number and then i do following

```
tail +6183313 test.log | grep 'exception'
```

sample logs

```
2014-02-17 10:15:02,625 | WARN  | m://mEndpoint | oSccMod | 262 - com.sm.sp-client - 0.0.0.R2D03-SNAPSHOT | 1201 or 101 is returned as exception code from SP, but it is ignored
2014-02-17 10:15:02,625 | WARN  | m://mEndpoint | oSccMod | 262 - com.sm.sp-client - 0.0.0.R2D03-SNAPSHOT | SP error ignored and mock success returned
2014-02-17 10:15:02,626 | INFO  | 354466740-102951 | ServiceFulfill | 183 - org.apache.cxf | Outbound Message
```

Please suggest any better alternative to perform above task.

Comment: Can you show small sample of test.logs data?

Comment: How can we use the same between two times ? I wanna execute in older files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With GNU `date`, one can use:

```
 grep "^$(date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" test.logs | grep 'exception'| mail -s "exceptions in last hour of test.logs" ImranRazaKhan
```

The first step above is to select all log entries from the last hour.  This is done with `grep` by looking for all lines beginning with the year-month-day and hour that matches one hour ago:

```
grep "^$(date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" test.logs
```

The next step in the pipeline is to select from those lines the ones that have exceptions:

```
grep 'exception'
```

The last step in the pipeline is to send out the mail:

```
mail -s "exceptions in last hour of test.logs" ImranRazaKhan
```

The above sends mail to ImranRazaKhan (or whatever email address you chose) with the subject line of "exceptions in last hour of test.logs".

The convenience of having the `-d` option to `date` should not be underestimated.  It might seem simple to subtract 1 from the current hour but, if the current hour is 12am, then we need to adjust both the day and the hour.  If the hour was 12am on the first of the month, we would also have to change the month.  And likewise for year.  And, of course, February requires special consideration during leap years.

#### Adapting the above to Solaris:

Consider three cases:

1. Under Solaris 11 or better, the GNU `date` utility is available at `/usr/gnu/bin/date`.  Thus, we need simply to specify a path for `date`:

   ```
    grep "^$(/usr/gnu/bin/date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" test.logs | grep 'exception'| mail -s "exceptions in last hour of test.logs" ImranRazaKhan
   ```
2. Under Solaris 10 or earlier, one can download & install GNU date
3. If GNU date is still not available, we need to find another way to find the date and time for one hour ago.  The simplest workaround is likely to select a timezone that is one hour behind your timezone.  If that timezone was, say, Hong Kong, then use:

   ```
    grep "^$(TZ=HongKong date +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" test.logs | grep 'exception'| mail -s "exceptions in last hour of test.logs" ImranRazaKhan
   ```

Comment: -d is illegal option in solaris

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan That is unfortunate.  I have one idea for a simple workaround: does Solaris's respect the `TZ` (timezone) environment variable?  In other words, if you run something like `TZ=Hongkong date +'%Y-%m-%d %H'`, do you get Hong Kong time?

Comment: Yes i got HongKong Time

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan Excellent!  See the update (but remember to replace HongKong with whatever timezone is 1 hour slower than your timezone).

Comment: On Solaris 11, use `/usr/gnu/bin/date` to get support for the -d option.   On Solaris 10 & earlier, you'd need to download & install GNU date.

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan I have updated the answer with Alanc's Solaris information.

Comment: That command will give you the log file entries from 1 hour **ago** and not the log file entries **within** the last hour, right? As an example, if it is 10:50AM, I will get the log file entries within 09:00AM to 09:59AM, but the entries from 10:00AM to 10:50AM will not be shown. I assume I have to combine it with `grep -E "^$(date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')|^$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H')"`

Comment: @MarkusZ. Yes.  But, in cases where the plan is to run the script hourly, then running it at 1 minute after the hour (10:01am) would work well and simpler.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  However, I modified it to check the output of grep.  If it is 0, send the mail. Otherwise, don't send it as grep didn't find anything.

Comment: How can we use the same between two times ? I wanna execute in older files.

Comment: That can be done.  How easy it is to do depends on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
dt="$(date -d '1 hour ago' "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")"

awk -v dt="$dt" '$0 ~ dt && /exceltion/' test.logs
```

Answer (score 1):

Scanning through millions lines of log sounds terribly inefficient. I would suggest changing log4j (what it looks like) configuration of your application to cut a new log file every hour. This way, tailing the most recent file becomes a breeze.